# In Rails 5 how can I create records in separate models with a single controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

I'm working through a Rails tutorial creating a database of James Bond movies. I have two models, movie.rb and theme_song.rb.  The two have the following association:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :theme_song
end
class ThemeSong < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

I've also represented this association in my routes.rb file:

```
resources :movies do
  resources :theme_songs
end
```

I need to enable a user to add the details of an additional movie into the database including general movie information and information about the theme song. The general information belongs in the Movie model, and the theme song information belongs in the ThemeSong model, as shown in the migrations below:

```
create_table :movies do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.datetime :release_date
  t.text :plot
  t.timestamps
end
create_table :theme_songs do |t|
  t.string :song
  t.string :artist
  t.references :movie, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

I have a movies_controller.rb controller and a new.html.erb view linked to the controller. The new.html.erb view has the following form coded into it:

```
<%= form_with model: @movie, local: true do |form| %>
  <p><strong>Movie Details</strong></p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Title:' %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Release date:' %>
    <%= form.text_field :release_date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Plot:' %>
    <%= form.text_area :plot %>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Soundtrack</strong></p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Theme song:' %>
    <%= form.text_area :song %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Artist:' %>
    <%= form.text_area :artist %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I need users to be able to fill out that form, submit it, and my controller's create action to add a new record in Movie with the general information, add a new record in ThemeSong with the soundtrack information, with both records linked in the association.

This is the code I've got so far in the relevant methods of my movies_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
  if @movie.save
    redirect_to @movie
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :release_date, :plot, :song, :artist)
end
```

Can anyone tell me what code I need to have in my create/movie_params methods? Or if I'm going about it in completely the wrong way and if so, how I should implement this?

I'm using Rails 5.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no information provided for the theme_song model, what fields need to be created or what data, but you probably don't want the data duplicated in both tables.

You're not going the wrong way, it might be easiest to add both sets of data to a single form uses accepts_nested_attributes.  Then tell your movies_controller params to also accept the nested traits.  Then it's rails magic to save the data in corresponding fashion.

## 1 Add the nesting option to the movie model

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :theme_song 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :theme_song
end
```

## 2 Nest the forms together

```
<%= form_with model: @movie, local: true do |form| %>
  <p><strong>Movie Details</strong></p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Title:' %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Release date:' %>
    <%= form.text_field :release_date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label 'Plot:' %>
    <%= form.text_area :plot %>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Soundtrack</strong></p>
  <%= form.fields_for :theme_song do |theme_song| %>
    <p>
      <%= theme_song.label 'Theme song:' %>
      <%= theme_song.text_area :song %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= theme_song.label 'Artist:' %>
      <%= theme_song.text_area :artist %>
    </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

## 3 Update Controller Params + Create new object

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
  if @movie.save
    redirect_to @movie
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def new
  @movie = Movie.new
  @movie.build_theme_song
end
private

def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :release_date, :plot, :song, :artist, theme_song_attributes: [:song, :artist, :id])
end
```

Two things to note here, the first is that in the new action you need to make sure to build the nested record.  Secondly the nested attributes are added to the params in the form of an array, it has to be this way.

## SideNote

Using this method has it's limitations.  You should know that this means that if two different movies use the same Theme Song, you'll have 2 movie records and 2 theme song records.  That might make it slower/harder to say "show me all the movies that this song is in", because then you have to account for user error and spelling in searching by name.  You might find, that in the future, it would be better to have a Movie record, a Theme Song record and a MovieThemeSongs record, which essentially joins the two.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. I've incorporated your solution into my edit and update actions as well as new and create.

Can I ask how you think I should modify my index action so the view that lists details of all the movies will also list their individual songs using the information in the associated records in ThemeSong model?

This is my current index action: 

  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

I'm not sure what code to write to prepare data for the index view to use to render the soundtrack details next to all the movie names. Is there a built in method I can use?

Comment: You get child records for free.  @movies[0].theme_song.artist

Comment: Not a problem, welcome to the fabulously lovely mad house that is StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#configuring-the-model) which allows you to have a nested form for `theme_song` inside your `movie` form:

Add it to your `Movie` model:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :theme_song

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :theme_song
end
```

in your movies controller:

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.new
  @movie.build_theme_song
end

private

def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :release_date, :plot, :song, :artist, theme_song_attributes: [:song, :artist])
end
```

finally, inside your `movie` form use `fields_for` helper to add fields for the movie's `theme_song`:

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  theme song:
  <ul>
  <%= f.fields_for @movie.theme_song do |theme_song_form| %>
    <li>
    <%= theme_song_form.label :song %>
    <%= theme_song_form.text_field :song %>
    ...
    </li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
<% end %>
```

Now, when you submit the form it will create a `movie` record and `theme_song` record for that movie.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Would your solution work even without adding the line "@movie.build_theme_song" to my 'new' controller action as shown in the answer above?

Comment: No, I actually missed that. You should have `@movie.build_theme_song` in your `new` action to have one set of empty fields for the `theme_song` in your `movie` form. see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms